# How to Authenticate other user from the other user in adf?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have a problem where an **Admin user**, who has logged-in,  has to authenticate **other authorized users**.

     *For example*- **Admin user** can do the authentication of the **employee user** to update his information.

For this we are using the below code, which we used during logged-in.

```
    Subject mySubject = Authentication.login(handler);

    ServletAuthentication.runAs(mySubject, request);
    ServletAuthentication.generateNewSessionID(request);
```

**Problem**  - If we do this, it is overriding the existing ADF SecurityContext, 
 so that even if the admin user logged-in, it is only showing the modules of the employee user.

Any suggestions would be granted.

Answer (score 1):

> > ServletAuthentication.generateNewSessionID(request);

Can you try without this piece? This tells the server to create a new session and effectively a new security context for the non-admin user. This will obviously overwrite the existing session, whereas all you need is to check the authenticity of another user, while logged in as admin.